# How can I show the progress of a FTPWebRequest file upload in a progress bar in a browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I show the progress of a FTPWebRequest file uplaod in a progress bar in a browser?

In my c# MVC 4 application I have implemented the .Net example of the Blueimp file upload example found here:

http://www.webtrendset.com/2011/06/22/complete-code-example-for-using-blueimp-jquery-file-upload-control-in-asp-net/

This uploaded uses the jquery.fileupload-ui.js plug-in.

I have modified the handler.ashx   in the MVC app to use FTPWebRequest to upload files to an FTP server.

The progress bar works when I start uploading a file but the progress indicator doesn’t accurately shows  the state of the progress

The progress bar in the browser always indicate that progress has been completed in the browser way before the FTPWebRequest  even start.

My handler looks something like this

```
    public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"; //"application/json";

                HttpContext postedContext = HttpContext.Current;


                var r = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ViewDataUploadFilesResult>();

                var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                foreach (string file in context.Request.Files)
                {
                    var hpf = context.Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFile;

uplaodFiles(hpf,pid, id);

   private UploadState uplaodFiles(HttpPostedFile file,Guid pid, string id)
        {


                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                request.Timeout = 3600000;

                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpuser, ftpassword);

                byte[] fileData = null;

                using (Stream input = file.InputStream)
                {
                    using (Stream output = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        input.CopyTo(output);
                    }
                }
```

I have intentionally omitted parts of the code example above

Comment: did you got any solution to show progress bar on ftpwebrequest ?

Answer (score 0):

http://tim.mackey.ie/FtpWebRequestWithProgressBarCFtp.aspx

look at the above link. It gives your answer

Comment: I saw that answer before but this is web MVC application. Thats the tricky part. If this were a regular form application it would be much easier

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've worked out at least most of the issues involved in FtpWebRequest for an MVC application.   Two quick questions, please.   Does your implementation support upload of VERY large files?  (I'm writing my first MVC app which needs to upload very large files (from 500MB to nearly 6GB) via FTP to an FileZilla FTP server co-located on the same VM with the MVC UI app).

If it does, would you consider posting a download link to the code you're using in your view, its controller, and the revised handler.ashx as well as what is necessary to wire up the handler?

I've found plenty of examples for non-web apps and a few for old-style server-side ASP.Net apps, but none at all for MVC that can overcome the 2GB limit for uploads with techniques that require IIS buffering of the entire file.

Thanks!
-Bob